# C# Call a method on button click of a form

Tags: c#, class, methods

I've been trying to do this all day and I don't see any helpful resources to resolve this issue.

I want to call `Server()` in the `MyTcpListener` class from the `Dashboard` form when a button is clicked.

Thanks in advance.

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace Csearch
{
    class MyTcpListener
    {
        public static void Server()
        {
            TcpListener server = null;
            try
            {
                // Set the TcpListener on port 13000.
                Int32 port = 13000;
                IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

                // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
                server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

                // Start listening for client requests.
                server.Start();

                // Buffer for reading data
                Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
                String data = null;

                // Enter the listening loop.
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");

                    // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
                    // You could also use server.AcceptSocket() here.
                    TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

                    data = null;

                    // Get a stream object for reading and writing
                    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                    int i;

                    // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
                    while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                        data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                        Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);

                        // Process the data sent by the client.
                        data = data.ToUpper();

                        byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

                        // Send back a response.
                        stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                        Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", data);
                    }

                    // Shutdown and end connection
                    client.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Stop listening for new clients.
                server.Stop();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nHit enter to continue...");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Csearch;

namespace Csearch
{

    
    public partial class Dashboard : Form
    {
        public Dashboard()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        // Server Start
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        { 

        }
        // Client Start
        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is the start of something very great");
             
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have defined `Server` as a static method in `MyTcpListener`, you can call it directly like followed.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyTcpListener.Server();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***Make your class as public static***

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace Csearch
{
    public static class MyTcpListener
    {
        public static void Server()
        {
            TcpListener server = null;
            try
            {
                // Set the TcpListener on port 13000.
                Int32 port = 13000;
                IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

                // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
                server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

                // Start listening for client requests.
                server.Start();

                // Buffer for reading data
                Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
                String data = null;

                // Enter the listening loop.
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");

                    // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
                    // You could also use server.AcceptSocket() here.
                    TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

                    data = null;

                    // Get a stream object for reading and writing
                    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                    int i;

                    // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
                    while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                        data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                        Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);

                        // Process the data sent by the client.
                        data = data.ToUpper();

                        byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

                        // Send back a response.
                        stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                        Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", data);
                    }

                    // Shutdown and end connection
                    client.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Stop listening for new clients.
                server.Stop();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nHit enter to continue...");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a class library and run it. Then add this .dll file to your main project by adding that dll as a reference. Then in your code add `using your_dll_name;`

Comment: Making a .dll file will help in many future projects just add'em to your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your class and method should be `public` and `static` like this. So that you can use it without creating an instance of the class and call it directly.

```
public static class MyTcpListener
{
    public static void Server()
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need changing your class (`MyTcpListener`) to the `public` and then call your method as below:

```
   namespace Csearch
   {
        public class MyTcpListener
        {
            public static void Server()
            {
             //......
            }
        }
    }
    ---------------------------------
    namespace Csearch
    { 
        public partial class Dashboard : Form
        {
            public Dashboard()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            // Server Start
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                MyTcpListener.Server();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I just tried that and it said it doesn't exist in the current context

Comment: If you mean it didn't recognize the ` MyTcpListener.Server()` command,
It must recognize that because both of them have the same namespace,
You can also click on the ` MyTcpListener.Server()` command and press key `Alt+Enter`
 could you take a photo of your project solution?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/tkiu1j https://prnt.sc/tkiu7j
Alright there is my solution and the 2 projects

Comment: So, where did you create `MyTcpListener Class`?,  I didn't see that in your picture

Comment: I created it first picture line 10